# What happens to assets intended for incorporation that never forms?

Tags: ownership, incorporation, partnership

I purchased two domain names with intention to use in a company with a partner.  We both signed a Letter of Agreement that these domains were to be used in the not-yet-formed company, and otherwise not to be used or released.  They never compensated me for this purchase.

Later, the other party declined to form the company (notification via email and text).

I've tried to get them to agree to split them (they take one, I keep one), but they show no interest and only respond with delaying tactics.

It's been 5 months.

At what point do these domains legally belong to me?

Answer (score 3):

I would imagine they are yours and were always yours. You bought them. You intended to either give them to the company as a gift, sell them to the company or sign them over to the company as part of your initial capital contribution. Without a company none of those can happen.